# Checkout.js + Server-Side -> country_code and phone issues using REST API /v1/payments/payment

Tags: rest, api, paypal

Without avail, I cannot get the country_code (CA) or phone to fill up after successfully calling create payment.

Country always show up as "United States" and Phone is "+1".

With or without shipping_address, shipping_preference: NO_SHIPPING.  Using so-called examples (which might be outdated or not correctly documented), and the API documentation, which would be great to have examples included...

This is the create-payment query in json.  I'm getting the same structure back with the following additions:

- id:PAY-xxx
- state:created
- phone in payer_info (but no country_code as expected from the API)
- created_time
- ...and...
- PayPal's links in links.

Which indicate that the call was successful.

Either I should ditch "/v1/payments/payment" for something else I'm not aware of, or Paypal API is not up-to-date.

----- json create-payment query -----

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal",
        "payer_info": {
            "email": "<snip>",
            "first_name": "Bob",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "billing_address": {
                "line1": "1 notre dame",
                "line2": "",
                "city": "Montreal",
                "country_code": "CA",
                "postal_code": "H1H 1H1",
                "phone": "011862212345678",
                "state": "QC"
            }
        }
    },
    "application_context": {
        "brand_name": "Server-side Test",
        "locale": "fr_CA",
        "landing_page": "Billing"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {   
            "description": "The payment transaction description.",
            "invoice_number": "5b5a38cb35bb7",
            "custom": "merchant custom data",
            "payment_options": {
                "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
            },
            "amount": {
                "total": "5.75",
                "currency": "CAD",
                "details": {
                    "subtotal": "5",
                    "tax": "0.75"
                }
            },
            "item_list": {
                "items": [
                    {   
                        "name": "item 1",
                        "description": "item 1 description",
                        "quantity": "1",
                        "price": "1",
                        "tax": "0.15",
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    {   
                        "name": "item 2",
                        "description": "item 2 description",
                        "quantity": "2",
                        "price": "2",
                        "tax": "0.6",
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    }
                ],
                "shipping_address": {
                    "recipient_name": "Bob Smith",
                    "line1": "1 notre dame",
                    "line2": "",
                    "city": "Montreal",
                    "country_code": "CA",
                    "postal_code": "H1H 1H1",
                    "phone": "011862212345678",
                    "state": "QC"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http:\/\/<snip>\/return.php",
        "cancel_url": "http:\/\/<snip>\/cancel.php"
    }
}
```

Comment: found 1/2 of the solution: locale: fr_CA will bring Canada (see checkout.js for what is supported) into the form, without locale I'm guessing you'll always get US.

Comment: And for the phone number, it is taking from the "shipping_address" which is part of "item_list".  You need to fill it up (the same as your "billing_address" to fillup the paypal checkout for your customer.  Thx  for the help of Adam at Paypal.